# How to run test methods (in Visual Studio) in Microsoft Test Manager?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, microsoft-test-manager

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and Microsoft Test Manager. In my project, I have written a test class with some test methods (i.e. Assert this and Assert that).

How do I actually run them in Microsoft Test Manager? I have created a Test Plan and added Test Cases, but how do I actually link my test methods to the test case? I've already looked online and on the Microsoft website, but it wasn't helpful and they were skipping so many steps.

What do I need to configure in Visual Studio? in Microsoft Test Manager?

Answer (score 0):

The test case must be associated with an automated test. MTM test cases have fields for "automation status" and "associated automation", but the later cannot be set from within MTM, it has to be set from Visual Studio.

Open Team Explorer in Visual Studio and use it to find and open the test case with a query. On the right hand side of the "associated automation" tab there is an ellipsis, click it and select the test to be run. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details. Note that when the test case is opened within MTM the ellipsis is not shown. I like to think of "*pushing test automation from Visual Studio into MTM*" being the method and that test cannot be "*pulled into MTM*".

Comment: When I find my "Test Case" in the query and then go to "Associated Automation" --> "Automated Test Name" --> [...], but I have no options listed? I'm guessing I didn't check my test project into the source control and add it to the build definition -- how do I even do this?

Comment: @mute The Microsoft page I linked to says "*After you create your automated test, you must check in your test project that contains the automated test and make sure that the test project is part of your build definition. Then you associate the automated test with a test case that has been added to a test plan that uses this build*".

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out eventually. And now I just need to set up a test controller and environment... I wish there was some more documentation on this. The Microsoft Help pages is overly simplified and assumes everything works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Visit [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd380741.aspx) URL

Here it is very well explained how to associate a test method to a test case.